# How do I successfully navigate to another screen screen in React Native?

Tags: typescript, react-native, android-studio, navigation

I have two screens:

App.tsx

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { NativeStackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { RootStackParamList } from '../Router';

type AppProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, "App">;

export default function App({navigation}: AppProps) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image style={styles.startLogo} source={require('../../assets/logo_transparent-shippr-red.png')}/>
      <View style={styles.btns}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnSI}>
              <Text style={styles.btnText}>Sign In</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnSU} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("SignUp")}>
              <Text style={styles.btnText}>Sign Up</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

SignUp.tsx

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image, Button, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { NativeStackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { RootStackParamList } from '../Router';

type SignUpProps = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, "SignUp">;

export default function SignUp({navigation}: SignUpProps) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        
      </View>
    );
}
```

This is the navigator:

```
import App from "./Components/App";
import SignUp from "./Components/SignUp";
import { NavigationContainer, ParamListBase, RouteProp } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator, NativeStackNavigationProp } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

export type RootStackParamList = {
    App: undefined;
    SignUp: undefined;
};

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

export default function Router() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="App">
                <Stack.Screen name="App" component={App}/>
                <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignUp}/>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

This is the error that appears in Android Studio. It says "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')":
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEiFz.jpg)

I don't want to pass any parameters to the SignUp route.

I already looked at the documentation and it says that SignUp needs to be undefined.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75574449/how-do-i-pass-props-to-bottomtabstack-component-nested-within-a-screenstack-comp/75574720#75574720